# How to create batch process to upload Oracle DB data to AWS Data Exchange?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, batch-processing, data-exchange

I am looking for scope where i can send data from oracle db to AWS Data exchange without any manual intervention?

Comment: In reading [Publishing Products - AWS Data Exchange User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/publishing-products.html), it seems that the data files need to be in Amazon S3. Therefore, you would need to find a way to automate the export of the data from Oracle to S3 objects.

Comment: Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/publish-and-update-data-products-dynamically-with-aws-data-exchange/) option for you?

Comment: yes  this was helpful...one way to do it...trying to find any rest call to aws  dataexchange to load data directly in dataexchange

Answer (score 0):

In January 2022, AWS Data Exchange launched support for data sets backed by Amazon Redshift; the same [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/publishing-products.html#publish-Redshift-product) referenced by [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein), above, shows you how you can create a data set using Amazon Redshift datashares. If you are able to move data from the Oracle database to Amazon Redshift, this option may work for you.

AWS Data Exchange just announced a preview of data sets using AWS Lake Formation, which allows you to share data from your Lake Formation data lake, which has support for Oracle databases running in Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) or hosted in Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2). Steps to create this kind of product can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/publishing-products.html#publish-LF-data-product).